# Limit 10 characters is numbers and only 1 dot

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having a regex problem when input
That's the requirement: limit 10 characters (numbers) including dots, and only 1 dot is allowed
My current code is only 10 characters before and after the dot.

```
^[0-9]{1,10}\.?[0-9]{0,10}$
```

thank for support.

Comment: Why do you have this requirement?  You'll accept a max or 9 or 10 digits, depending on the decimal point.  Why not set a fixed precision?

Comment: Do you wish to match `'12'`? `'.'`? `''`?

Comment: In addition to Cary's comment, it would help to see examples of what you want to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assert 10 chars in the string being either `.` or a digit.

Then you can match optional digits, and optionally match a dot and again optional digits:

```
^(?=[.\d]{10}$)\d*(?:\.\d*)?$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=[.\d]{10}$)` Positive lookahead, assert 10 chars `.` or digit till the end of string
- `\d*` Match optional digits
- `(?:\.\d*)?` Optionally match a `. and optional digits
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EoJM10/1).

If the pattern should not end on a dot:

```
^(?=[.\d]{10}$)\d*(?:\.\d+)?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/U4KYAj/1)

Answer (score 1):

The decimal point throws a wrench into most single pattern approaches.  I would probably use an alternation here:

```regex
^(?:\d{1,10}|(?=\d*\.)(?!\d*\.\d*\.)[0-9.]{2,11})$
```

This pattern says to match:

```regex
^                   from the start of the number
(?:
    \d{1,10}        a pure 1 to 10 digit integer
    |               OR
    (?=\d*\.)       assert that one dot is present
    (?!\d*\.\d*\.)  assert that ONLY one dot is present
    [0-9.]{2,11}    match a 1 to 10 digit float
)
$                   end of the number
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lookahead to achieve your goals.

First, looking at your regex, you've used `[0-9]` to represent all digit characters.  We can shorten this to `\d`, which means the same thing.

Then, we can focus on the requirement that there be only one dot.  We can test for this with the following pattern:

```
^\d*\.?\d*$
```

- `\d*` means any number of digit characters
- `\.?` matches one literal dot, optionally
- `\d*` matches any number of digit characters after the dot
- `$` anchors this to the end of the string, so the match can't just end before the second dot, it actually has to fail if there's a second dot

Now, we don't actually want to consume all the characters involved in this match, because then we wouldn't be able to ensure that there are <=10 characters.  Here's where the lookahead comes in: We can use the lookahead to ensure that our pattern above matches, but not actually perform the match.  This way we verify that there is only one dot, but we haven't actually consumed any of the input characters yet.  A lookahead would look like this:

```
^(?=\d*\.?\d*$)
```

Next, we can ensure that there are aren't more than 10 characters total.  Since we already made sure there are only dots and digits with the above pattern, we can just match up to 10 of any characters for simplicity, like so:

```
^.{1,10}$
```

Putting these two patterns together, we get this:

```
^(?=\d*\.?\d*$).{1,10}$
```

This will only match number inputs which have 10 or fewer characters and have no more than one dot.

If you would like to ensure that, when there is a dot, there is also a digit accompanying it, we can achieve this by adding another lookahead.  The only case that meets this condition is when the input string is just a dot (`.`), so we can just explicitly rule this case out with a negative lookahead like so:

```
(?!\.$)
```

Adding this back in to our main expression, we get:

```
^(?=\d*\.?\d*$)(?!\.$).{1,10}$
```

Comment: @Charlie Armstrong
can you help me add one more idea that when there is a dot, there must be at least 1 number?

Comment: @HoangDuy You can just add another lookahead.  It should match any number of characters (`.*`) and then a digit (`\d`).  So it would be `(?=.*\d)`.  I'll add this to my answer.

Comment: @HoangDuy I changed my solution to your "at least one digit" question.  In the answer, I've used a negative lookahead instead.  That way just seems simpler to me, and it's one character shorter.

Comment: if you change the first look ahead to must start with digit (`d+` not `d*`) then you can remove the 2nd look ahead and end up with:  `^(?=\d+\.?\d*$).{1,10}$`

Comment: @OferSkulsky I thought about that, too, but that assumes you want the digit to come before the dot.  What about an input like `.2`?

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong to be able to start with a `.`, you can do it like this: `^(?=\d*\.?\d+$).{1,10}$`

Comment: @OferSkulsky Right, but then you can't end with a dot, like in `2.`.  The way Huang Duy has worded it, either `2.` or `.2` should match, but not `.`.

Comment: @Ofer Skulsky
tks you for help, Your method also applies, I don't care too much about whether there must be a number in front of the dot!

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong if you want  to capture the group not just match the string, surround the hole expression with ()

Comment: @OferSkulsky I'm not sure why that is desirable.  Usually capturing groups are used when you only want part of the match, but in this case, the full match is the desired result.  If you like working with capturing groups, you can refer to the full match as capturing group 0.  (Or, in a replacement string, as `$&`)  Putting the expression in parenthesis () just puts the match in capturing group 1, so there's really no difference other than the number.